# Cascade delete from lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, column, cascading

I have 3 lists with a lookup field to a document library.
This fields is created from XML (deployed) with this properties:

```
Indexed="TRUE"
RelationshipDeleteBehavior="Cascade"
```

Now, what I would expect is, when I delete the document, the linked items should be removed as well. For one list, this is the case. But for the other ones, the item isn't removed. Only the lookup value is made empty.

Any ideas what the problem could be? Every linked item should be removed!

**Update 1**

When I want to delete a document, I get this popup-message:

> Sending this item to the site Recycle Bin will also send any related
>   items in the following lists to the site Recycle Bin: [**<LIST NAME>**].
>   Are you sure you want to send the item(s) to the site Recycle Bin?

With <LIST NAME> set to the correctly working list.

**Update 2**

I thought that maybe every lookup field should have a unique lookup field. So I tried to create a new one, changed into the contenttype and listdefinition. But with same result. Only the one list removes the items, not the other ones.

Comment: Are the other lookup columns in the other lists set as cascade delete?

Comment: It's the same lookup column they use, so all with properties above. Also, contenttypes and fields in listdefinition are set with these properties.